# Why is the 64bit JVM faster than the 32bit one?

Tags: java, 64-bit, jvm, performance

Recently I've been doing some benchmarking of the write performance of my company's database product, and I've found that simply switching to a 64bit JVM gives a consistent 20-30% performance increase.

I'm not allowed to go into much detail about our product, but basically it's a column-oriented DB, optimised for storing logs. The benchmark involves feeding it a few gigabytes of raw logs and timing how long it takes to analyse them and store them as structured data in the DB. The processing is very heavy on both CPU and I/O, although it's hard to say in what ratio.

A few notes about the setup:

```
Processor: Xeon E5640 2.66GHz (4 core) x 2
RAM: 24GB
Disk: 7200rpm, no RAID
OS: RHEL 6 64bit
Filesystem: Ext4
JVMs: 1.6.0_21 (32bit), 1.6.0_23 (64bit)
Max heap size (-Xmx): 512 MB (for both 32bit and 64bit JVMs)
```

Constants for both JVMs:

- Same OS (64bit RHEL)
- Same hardware (64bit CPU)
- Max heap size fixed to 512 MB (so the speed increase is not due to the 64bit JVM using a larger heap)

For simplicity I've turned off all multithreading options in our product, so pretty much all processing is happening in a single-threaded manner. (When I turned on multi-threading, of course the system got faster, but the ratio between 32bit and 64bit performance stayed about the same.)

So, my question is... Why would I see a 20-30% speed improvement when using a 64bit JVM? Has anybody seen similar results before?

My intuition up until now has been as follows:

- 64bit pointers are bigger, so the L1 and L2 caches overflow more easily, so performance on the 64bit JVM is worse.
- The JVM uses some fancy pointer compression tricks to alleviate the above problem as much as possible. Details on the Sun site [here](http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops).
- The JVM is allowed to use more registers when running in 64bit mode, which speeds things up slightly.

Given the above three points, I would expect 64bit performance to be slightly slower, or approximately equal to, the 32bit JVM.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Clarified some points about the benchmark environment.

Comment: Do you run your 32bit JVM on 64bit OS? If yes, than you must remember that 32bit app on 64bit os will be "emulated", so it will loose some performance. Check performance on both 32bit OS -> 32bit JVM and 64bit OS -> 64bit JVM

Comment: Also, could this be memory-related?  That is, on the 64-bit version where you have the ability to access more memory, could it just be that the GC doesn't have to run as much or as aggressively because resources aren't as tight?

Comment: Yes, please make sure the benchmark is run with same memory settings.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that both JVMs are running on the same 64bit OS and CPU, with the same heap size. I've edited the question to clarify these points.

Comment: what if you run with -XX:+UseCompressedOops

Comment: List exact launch parameters and JVM's.

Comment: Also you should profile with e.g. jvisualvm to locate bottlenecks.  These are where the time is spent so knowing them (in both scenarios) will most likely point directly to the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without knowing your hardware I'm just taking some wild stabs

- Your specific CPU may be using microcode to 'emulate' some x86 instructions -- most notably the x87 ISA
- x64 uses sse math instead of x87 math, I've noticed a %10-%20 speedup of some math-heavy C++ apps in this case. Math differences could be the real killer if you're using `strictfp`.
- Memory. 64 bits gives you much more address space. Maybe the GC is a little less agressive on 64 bits mode because you have extra RAM.
- Is your OS is in 64b mode and running a 32b jvm via some wrapper utility?

Comment: The heap size was fixed to 512m for both JVMs, so I don't think memory/GC issues come into play here. But your points about 32bit/x86 emulation and different math instruction sets sound very plausible. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: @Chris I see you selected my answer. Care to share which point it ended up being?

Comment: To be honest, I'm still not sure. Being a DB, the application is not really that math-heavy (in particular very few floating point calculations), so I think the 32bit JVM slowdown is most likely due to emulation. As you suggested, this emulation would be either on the OS side, running the JVM in a "32bit mode", or on the CPU side, emulating x86 instructions in microcode. Currently we don't have the hardware available to try the benchmark on equivalent hardware and a 32bit OS and/or CPU, so I can't confirm this.

Comment: Emulation gets my vote from my research on the topic.

Answer (score 10):

From: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_performance

"Generally, the benefits of being able to address larger amounts of memory come with a small performance loss in 64-bit VMs versus running the same application on a 32-bit VM.  This is due to the fact that every native pointer in the system takes up 8 bytes instead of 4.  The loading of this extra data has an impact on memory usage which translates to slightly slower execution depending on how many pointers get loaded during the execution of your Java program.  The good news is that with AMD64 and EM64T platforms running in 64-bit mode, the Java VM gets some additional registers which it can use to generate more efficient native instruction sequences.  These extra registers increase performance to the point where there is often no performance loss at all when comparing 32 to 64-bit execution speed.
The performance difference comparing an application running on a 64-bit platform versus a 32-bit platform on SPARC is on the order of 10-20% degradation when you move to a 64-bit VM.  On AMD64 and EM64T platforms this difference ranges from 0-15% depending on the amount of pointer accessing your application performs."

Answer (score 2):

My best guess, based on a quick google for 32- vs 64-bit performance charts,
is that 64 bit I/O is more efficient.  I suppose you do a lot of I/O...

If memcpy is involved when moving the data, it's probably more efficient to copy longs than ints.

Comment: That's interesting, I've never heard of 64bit I/O being more efficient, although I guess it makes sense. I'll try and google some hard data on that.

Comment: Could you share the link to the charts, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The 64-bit instruction set has 8 more registers, this should make the code faster overall.

But, since processsors nowaday mostly wait for memory or disk, i suppose that either the memory subsystem or the disk i/o might be more efficient in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Realize that the 64-bit JVM is not magic pixie dust that makes Java apps
go faster. The 64-bit JVM allows heaps >> 4 GB and, as such, only makes sense
for applications which can take advantage of huge memory on systems which
have it.

Generally there is either a slight improvement (due to certain hardware
optimizations on certain platforms) or minor degradation (due to increased
pointer size). Generally speaking there will be a need for fewer GC's -- but
when they do occur they will likely be longer.

In memory databases or search engines that can use the increased memory
for caching objects and thus avoid IPC or disk accesses will see the biggest
application level improvements. In addition a 64-bit JVM will also
allow you to run many, many more threads than a 32-bit one, because
there's more address space for things like thread stacks, etc. The
maximum number of threads generally for a 32-bit JVM is ~1000but ~100000 threads with a 64-bit JVM.

Some drawbacks though:
Additional issues with the 64-bit JVM are that certain client
oriented features like Java Plug-in and Java Web Start
are not supported. Also any native code would also need
to be compatible (e.g. JNI for things like Type II JDBC drivers).
This is a bonus for pure-Java developers as pure apps should
just run out of the box.

More on this Thread at [Java.net](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/performance/general-performance-discussion/which-fastest-32-or-64-bits-jvm-and-linux-0)

Comment: Just a note. Web start does work with a 64 bit JRE client. I've done this with Java 6 and 7.

Comment: The number of threads in modern JVMs (which use native threads instead of green threads) is typically limited by the operating system, not the JVM.